# How can I update a ShinyR header object (e.g. h1())

Tags: r, shiny

I have a ui.R file that includes the following:

```
h1("Hello")
```

I would like to update this value depending on input from a text field and/or a couple of drop down select menus. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at `renderUI`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use it (minimal app):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('input1', 'Select a Number', choices = seq(1:5)),
  uiOutput('output1')
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$output1 <- renderUI({
    h1(paste('You selected number: ', input$input1))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I had googled around but had not come across this

Comment: No problem. This approach works for pretty much any dynamic UI you want to generate from the server side.